# How can I use a specific guild ID in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I currently am working in a script that's automatically updated, and not called by any command or message. Thus, I have no message variable to call message.guild.id with. I am making a bot for one specific server, and I need my code to edit a specific channel within that server, thus needing the server ID. I tried

```
let server = client.guilds.get('<guild id>'), channel;
```

and using the server variable to find the specific channel I want it to edit. This however gives an error. Am I missing any dependencies, or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.guilds.get` does not exist anymore. Use `client.guilds.cache.get`

```js
let server = client.guilds.cache.get('<guild id>')
```